# How spring batch share data between job

Tags: spring, caching, spring-batch

I have one query on Spring Batch Job.
I want to share data of one job with another job in same execution context. Is it possible? If so, then how?

My requirement is caching. I have file, where some data is stored. My job runs daily and need data of that file. I don't want to read file by my job daily. instead of it, I want to store data of file in cache(Hash Map). So when same job runs next day, it will use data from cache only. Is it possible in spring batch?

Your suggestion are welcome.

Comment: How to trigger your batch job? Are you using webcontainer(spring batch admin) or standalone java project?

Comment: i am using Quartz Scheduler(exter shceduler) to invoke the Job. My question is simple. I want to hold data in cache (i.e dont want to read data from datasource as property file/database daily). I will invoke datasource only if my application restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spring initialize bean which initializes your cache at startup.

Add initialize bean to your application context;

```
<bean id="yourCacheBean" class="yourpackage.YourCacheBean" init-method="initialize">
</bean>
```

YourCacheBean looks like;

```
public class YourCacheBean {

    private Map<Object, Object> yourCache;

    public void initialize() {
        //TODO: Intialize your cache
    }
}
```

Give the initialize bean to the itemReader or itemProcessor or itemWriter in job.xml;

```
<bean id="exampleProcessor" class="yourpackage.ExampleProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="cacheBean" ref="yourCacheBean" />
</bean>
```

ExampleProcessor looks like;

```
public class ExampleProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    private YourCacheBean cacheBean;

    public String process(String arg0) {
        return "";
    }

    public void setCacheBean(YourCacheBean cacheBean) {
        this.cacheBean = cacheBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy :-) I have too decided almost similar solution for same. I am using IntialzingBean and @PostContruct for same.

Comment: I glad to hear that :) My suggestion may be old fashion because of xml based configuration. May be annotation based configuration is available. I have one more advice for your cache. I believe you will need a cache eviction. Open a rest service for refreshing your cache :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a job to import file into database. Other jobs will use data from database as a cache. 
Another way may be to read file into a Map<> and serialize object to a file than de-serialize when need (but I still prefer database as cache)

Comment: I want to hold cache data as object(MAP) for long term i.e. till server dosent restart to incorporate any change in application. i was thinking to hold property file data in Static Map. But i am not sure, how Garbage Collector will behave with static map. I dont want that Garbage collector delete cache data. So that I can use till application dosent restart.

Answer (score 0):

Spring have a cache annotation that may help that kind of case and it is really easy to implement. The first call to a method will be executed, afterwards if you call the same method with exactly the same arguments, the value will be returned by the cache.

Here you have a little tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

In your case, if your call to read the file is always with the same arguments will work as you want. Just take care of TTL.